# Error in Tic-Tac-Toe Game

Tags: c++, increment, do-while, tic-tac-toe

I'm having trouble with this C++ code when creating a program that simulates a tic-tac-toe game. The game runs "fine", displays the winner, validates input, etc., but if the player 'X' wins, the player 'O' is still allowed to make another move before the winner is announced.

```
do
{
    int turn = 0;

    if (turn % 2 == 0)
    {
        cout << "Player X, Row and Column: ";
        cin >> row >> column;

        while (array[(row-1)][(column-1)] != '*')
        {
            cout << "Invalid move try again \n";
            cout << "Player X, Row and Column: ";
            cin >> row >> column;
        }

        array[row-1][column-1] = 'X';
        showArray(array);
        results = checkWin(array);
    }

    if (turn % 2 != 0)
    {
        cout << "Player O, Row and Column: ";
        cin >> row >> column;

        while (array[row-1][column-1] != '*')
        {
            cout << "Invalid move try again \n";
            cout << "Player O, Row and Column: ";
            cin >> row >> column;
        }
        array[row-1][column-1] = 'O';
        showArray(array);
        results = checkWin(array);
    }
    turn++;
}while (results == 0);
```

I am using a do-while loop that alternates between two players. When I place the incrementing 'turn++;' statement outside both if blocks, the program only allows the player 'X' to move. When I place the 'turn++;' statement within the player 'X' if block, it alternates, but I run into the problem described above. If you have any suggestions please give them. Thanks.

Comment: Where is the condition for draw?

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips on how to debug your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time your loop iterates the turn value gets initialize to 0, that is why every time player 'X' get the chance.

So place int turn = 0, outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Move `int turn = 0;` out of your loop. e.g :

```
int turn = 0;
do {
    doSomeThing();
    turn++;
} while(someThingHappen());
```

If you place `int turn = 0` inside your loop, every loop will start with `turn = 0`

Answer (score 0):

As @hai_uit said, move `int turn = 0;` out of the loop. Most of the time it is a good idea to declare all variables outside of any loops or if statements.

Comment: Thank you! Yea I see where the index/counter variable resets after each loop.